# Using openpyxl in python 2.7

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl in this code

```
import sys
from openpyxl import *

excel_file    = sys.argv[1]
work_folder   = sys.argv[2]
sheet_name    = sys.argv[3]

file_full = work_folder + "\\"+ sheet_name + '.txt'

wb = load_workbook(excel_file)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

delimiter = ","

with open((file_full), encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        sheet.append(line.split(delimiter))

wb.Save()
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error

> ```
>  line 2, in <module> from openpyxl import *
>  ImportError: No module named openpyxl
> ```

I thought that openpyxl was not installed propely but when I tried to install it, it said requeirement already satisfied.

[image]

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm not using IDE, just notepad++

Comment: `For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must restart the interpreter` its from official python 2.7 documentation, maybe it will help

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. All we can see is that there's a problem with the import, there's no hint to what the problem actually is.

Comment: How can I get the full traceback? This is the only thing that shows up in the console:
"  File "filepath", line 2, in <module>
    from openpyxl import *
ImportError: No module named openpyxl"

Comment: That's fine... the `ImportError:...` line was the important part you didn't put in the question.

Comment: how are you executing your script? if you ran pip as `c:\python27\python.exe -m pip` you will need to run `c:\python27\python.exe path\to\your\script.py`

Comment: I'm running int he cmd : "python.exe script.py argument1 argument2 argument3"

Comment: is openpyxl listed if you `python.exe -m pip list` ?

Comment: I still dont know why it's not working but i installed the same way in Python 3.6 and now worked. 
Now it seems openpyxl cant open excel files with certain types of content and my file happens to be one them(I think it's a chart)...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174165/openpyxl-open-workbook